# semantic ui horizontal list seems broken in cards

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I was trying to get a horizontal ui list within a card, but the layout is all wrong

Outside a card, the list is just fine

[image]

but when I put the identical html unside a `ui card` then it goes like this

[image]

I have a codepen (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWmZOr) that illustrates the problem

Using semantic-ui 2.3.1

I was wondering if anyone knew if I was doing something wrong or if it's a limitation or bug of semantic-ui

thanks

the html is here

```
<body>
  <div class="ui horizontal list">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="ui avatar image" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/94d093eda664addd6e450d7e9881bcad?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="header">Tom</div>
        Top Contributor
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="ui avatar image" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/94d093eda664addd6e450d7e9881bcad?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="header">Christian Rocha</div>
        Admin
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="ui avatar image" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/94d093eda664addd6e450d7e9881bcad?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="header">Matt</div>
        Top Rated User
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui cards">

    <div class="ui card">

      <div class="content">
        <div class="ui horizontal list">
          <div class="item">
            <img class="ui avatar image" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/94d093eda664addd6e450d7e9881bcad?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="header">Tom</div>
              Top Contributor
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img class="ui avatar image" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/94d093eda664addd6e450d7e9881bcad?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="header">Christian Rocha</div>
              Admin
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img class="ui avatar image" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/94d093eda664addd6e450d7e9881bcad?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="header">Matt</div>
              Top Rated User
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This selector seems to be causing an issue for you:

`.ui.horizontal.list>.item`

As it is adding a margin-left where there shouldn't be.

The reason why the first one doesn't have this issue is because it is being targeted by a `first-child` psuedo selector.

[This screen cap of the inspector should make it clearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErXyH.png)

I suggest not using .item inside of a horizontal list, or something to that effect.

Best of luck!